# how can we implement a radio button instead of a drop down menu?

Tags: java, html, servlets

```
<form action="Operation">
            First number::<input type="text" name="firstno"></input></br>
            Second number::<input type="text" name="Secondno"></input></br>
            <select name="operation">
                <option>Add</option>
                <option>Substract</option>
                <option>Multiply</option>
                <option>Divide</option>
            </select> </br>
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
```

Here instead of a drop down menu I want to use a radio button. How can I implement this? Also I want to perform an operation in servlet page.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: @gerrytan Do not refer w3schools see: http://www.w3fools.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for radio buttons try this way

```
<form action="Operation">
            First number::<input type="text" name="firstno"></input></br>
            Second number::<input type="text" name="Secondno"></input></br>

<input type="radio" name="operation" value="add">add<br>
<input type="radio" name="operation" value="subtract">Substract<br>
<input type="radio" name="operation" value="Multiply">Multiply<br>
<input type="radio" name="operation" value="Divide">Divide<br>

            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
```

on the servlet try

```
String radio=request.getParameter("operation");
```

Answer (score 0):

change your input type="radio"